# Get difference between DateTime instances with clj-time

Tags: clojure, jodatime, clj-time

I am trying to calculate the difference between two DateTime instances using [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time). I looked through the documentation and found `clj-time.core/minus` and `clj-time.core/minus-` but both require an instance of `org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod` and not one of `DateTime`. I would prefer to use cli-time, but if no solution exists, what would be the cleanest method of calculating the delta using Joda Time?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use this snippet very often in my daily work:

```
(ns project.namespace1
  (:require [clj-time
              [core :as t]] )

(let [start-time (t/now)]
  ... do lots of work ...
  (t/in-millis (t/interval start-time (t/now))))
```

Comment: That works well. Thank you. I have one final question, however: is there no way to return an instance on which one can call `t/hour`, for example? Or do we have to do math with the milliseconds ourselves?

Comment: There's also `in-hours`, `in-days` and so on. Remember that `hour` is for querying "What hour of the day is this event?". An interval doesn't happen at a particular time of the day, so this question doesn't make any sense to ask.

Comment: So math it is then. Thanks for the help.